# Splitting JSON into an array

Tags: regex, vb.net

and before we continue i am follow aware of the JSON classes provided already. This is purely for my own learning.

I was practicing my regex today and wondered why this was not splitting or matching into a collection.

```
(s?)(?<=""\d+"":{).+(?=football.*)

    {
   "100":{
      "username":"j123",
      "id":10,
      "date":2014,
      "user":{
         "name":"John s",
      },
      "game":{
         "football":33
      }
   },
   "101":{
      "username":"j456",
      "id":11,
      "date":2014,
      "user":{
         "name":"John t",
      },
      "game":{
         "football":32
      }
   }
   }
}#
```

can some One kindly explain where i am going wrong. I dont need the football result just the parts between.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, lookbehinds cannot be variable width, as in: `(?<=""\d+"":{)`.  the \d`+` quantifier is not allowed. And the double quotes? also what is `(s?)`?  Did you mean `(\s?)`.

Comment: @MElliott: No, .NET regexes allow indefinite repetition inside lookbehind assertions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` is a *greedy* quantifier, so `.+` matches as many characters as possible, from `"100"` to the final `"football":32`.

By making the quantifier *lazy* (`.+?`) you tell the regex engine to end the match as early as possible.

(And you probably meant `(?s)` to allow the dot to match newlines).